# Display text values on stacked bar graph using plotly express in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly-express

I am working with plotly express in a Jupyter Notebook, doing a stacked bar chart. I'm trying to get the percentages in this sample data to display on the graph itself:

Sample Data:

| Group | Any Insurance | Employment Based | Medicaid | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group1 | 91.7 | 55.5 | 15.5 | 20.7 |
| Group2 | 89.6 | 46.3 | 28.5 | 14.8 |
| Group3 | 81.7 | 41.2 | 28.3 | 12.2 |
| Group4 | 94.1 | 61.4 | 15.8 | 16.9 |

I've tried text= and textposition = 'auto', like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

CG = pd.read_csv("CoverageGroups.csv", header=0)

    fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='Employment Based', x=CG.Group, y=CG['Employment Based'], marker_color='silver', textposition = 'auto'),
    go.Bar(name='Medicaid', x=CG.Group, y=CG['Medicaid'], marker_color='grey', textposition = 'auto'),
    go.Bar(name='Other', x=CG.Group, y=CG['Other'], marker_color='silver', textposition = 'auto'),
])
# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack',
                   title='Coverage by Group',
                   xaxis_title='Group',
                   yaxis_title='% Covered',
                   plot_bgcolor='white',
                )
fig.show()
```

But my resulting figure doesn't have any of the percentages displaying on the bars as desired:
[image: Resulting figure]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `text` attribute to `go.Bar` plot, which should contain the same value of y-axis.

**Full example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

CG = pd.read_csv("CoverageGroups.csv", header=0)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name='Employment Based', x=CG.Group, y=CG['Employment Based'], marker_color='silver',text=CG['Employment Based']))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name='Medicaid', x=CG.Group, y=CG['Medicaid'], marker_color='grey', text=CG['Medicaid']))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name='Other', x=CG.Group, y=CG['Other'], marker_color='silver', text=CG['Other'])),

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.update_traces(textposition = 'inside')
fig.show()
```

**Output**
[image]